# Javascript get width of img from path

Tags: javascript

i think there should be an easy solution for this, but I can't figure it out.
What I'm trying to do is to get the width/height of an image by its path (not rendered on screen).

Like:

```
var img = ImageInfo(path);
alert(img.width);
```

(I want to do this in plain javascript)

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
function getImageSize(imgSrc) {
     var imgLoader = new Image(); // create a new image object

    imgLoader.onload = function() { // assign onload handler
        var height = imgLoader.height;
        var width = imgLoader.width;
        alert ('Image size: '+width+'x'+height);
    }

    imgLoader.src = imgSrc; // set the image source
}
```

You basically create a new image using javascript. Assign the onload event, and then set the source and wait for image to load. when it's loaded the onload handler alerts the height and width of the image. check this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WeAxt/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Let `ImageInfo` function to accept a callback(ie: make it async).

```
function ImageInfo(path, onLoad) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = path;
  img.onload = function() {
    onLoad(img);
  }
}
```

Use it like:

```
ImageInfo(url, function(img) {
  alert(img.width);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var path = "http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110928222437/callofduty/images/4/4f/Personal_IW_FTW_Awesome_Face_100px.png";

var img = new Image();

img.src = path;
```

It's pretty simplified, but something alone these lines should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/s9QVp/1/